# What can't the NDK be used for?

Tags: c++, android, android-ndk

From the [official NDK site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html):

> The Android NDK... provides
>   headers and libraries that allow you
>   to build **activities, handle user
>   input, use hardware sensors, access
>   application resources, and more**,
>   when programming in C or C++. If you
>   write native code, your applications
>   are still packaged into an .apk file
>   and they still run inside of a virtual
>   machine on the device. The fundamental
>   Android application model does not
>   change.

Yet, it is always described as a **companion** tool to the Android SDK and as a toolset that allows to "implement **parts** of your applications using native-code languages such as C and C++".

My understanding from this is that, unlike the Java based SDK, the NDK is not designed to implement certain parts of an Android application.

Is this correct?

If so, what parts **doesn't** the NDK allow implementing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to note that the documentation you're referring to was around before the ndk was actually capable of dealing with things such as activities, and whatnot.  As such, back then what you would need to do is create an android app with the sdk, and at a bare minimum, you needed to create a java wrapper class for the activity lifecycle events, which called native code.  Also, if you wanted sound, or other interactions with the user, you would often have to use the sdk for that too.

Now however, it seems like you could potentially use the NDK for an entire app (although I haven't tried it yet), but if you wanted to use standard UI elements, such as a list to select a game file, I would still use the SDK for that.

Comment: @Leif thanks and +1 for explaining this so well. So do I understand from your answer that you can actually program an entire application using the NDK? How about a TTS application?

Comment: NDK does not support (not out of the box, anyway) garbage collection, like Java does :)

Comment: @Seva That's part of the deal when programming in C++. No problem there. I was mainly wondering what kind of an ordeal I might be getting myself into, if I choose to develop for the Android using C++ only. Is it possible at all?

Comment: You'll have to write a whole lot of cumbersome, hard to read Java reflection code. Or create/find and learn a wrapper library. Suffice it to say that instantiating a Java class and calling a method is 6 lines in C++, that's not counting the error handling. Java exceptions don't propagate to C++ exceptions (not out of the box, anyway).

Comment: @Seva Thanks and +1 again. So, from "instantiating a Java class and calling a method is 5 lines in C++" I understand that there are parts in Android that have no C++ interface. Is this correct?

Comment: The interface of 95% of the platform is in/for Java. It *can* be called from C++, but in a very roundabout manner. No *native* C++ interface would be a better way of putting it.

Comment: Also another problem you should be aware of when using the NDK, when android devices start running on more architectures than the two versions of arm that are mostly (although I don't believe exclusively) used, and supported by the ndk, you will have to recompile your code for those architectures.  The good news is that the ndk, based on the gnu toolchain can be retrofitted to compile for other architectures , but the bad news is that you may not have the libraries you need.  And @Seva is correct, if you're using the standard APIs a lot, the sdk will be a lot easier.

Comment: What the OP needs is a translation layer that abstracts away the pain of coding against raw JNI. A kind of ATL for Java. In conjuction with an object importer from Java metadata into C++ object prototypes, like the #import directive does in MS Native COM. However, the existence of such a library would only encourage perverts like the OP, and the overall quality of Android software ecosystem would probably suffer. A net loss for humanity as a whole, IMHO. Disclaimer: I personally prefer C++ to Java. However, I also strongly believe in using the right tools for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Check out NDK r5 (released Dec 2010). They've added a lot of support for native C++ coding, including native activities.